# How to write this generic function in TypeScript which merges array parameter and values into an object?

Tags: typescript, generics

I have written a function, which merges a keys array and a values array into an object. The implementation is just like below:

```js
function mergeToObject(keys: string[], values: string[]) {
  const object:? = {}
  for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    object[keys[i]] = values[i] // TypeScript complains it
  }
  return object
}
```

For illustrating the function, it behaves like below:

```js
mergeToObject(['a', 'b', 'c'], ['x', 'y', 'z']) // => { a: 'x', b: 'y', c: 'z' }
```

And also, I always pass `keys` param as a constant expression like `['a', 'b', 'c']`, but not a runtime value. so I guess it must exists a generic syntax exactly declaring the return type contains keys `a`, `b` and `c`.

For illustrating the behavior more concretely:

```js
const values = ['x', 'y', 'z']

// If I invoke as
const object = mergeToObject(['a', 'b', 'c'], values)
// Then the type of object should be `{ a: string, b: string, c: string }`
object.a // is ok
object.b // is ok
object.c // is ok
object.d // is not ok

// In other words, if I invoke as
const object = mergeToObject(['e', 'f', 'g'], values)
// Then the type of object should be `{ e: string, f: string, g: string }`
object.e // is ok
object.f // is ok
object.g // is ok
object.d // is not ok
```

So what is exactly the generic written? I'll sincerely appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Record`:

```
function mergeToObject(keys: string[], values: string[]) : Record<string, any> {
  const object: Record<string, any> = {}
  for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    object[keys[i]] = values[i] // TypeScript complains it
  }
  return object
}
```

More info here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#example-3

Note: I used `any` as type for the values, but if you prefer to constrain to string only, just change to it.

Comment: Since we already know that the type will always be `string` then better to use `Record<string, string>`

Comment: @decpk yes, that's the way I added a note. The original function is just for strings, but it works for any kind of values.

Answer (score 0):

**`SOLUTION 1`**

You can also create an interface and assing it to it as:

```
interface mergeObject {
  [k: string]: string
}
```

which means that `mergeObject` is an object of `key` and `value` as `string`

```js
interface mergeObject {
  [k: string]: string
}

function mergeToObject(keys: string[], values: string[]): mergeObject {
  const object: mergeObject = {}
  for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    object[keys[i]] = values[i] // TypeScript complains it
  }
  return object
}

const result = mergeToObject(['a', 'b', 'c'], ['x', 'y', 'z']) // => { a: 'x', b: 'y', c: 'z' }
console.log(result)
```

**`SOLUTION 2`**

```js
interface mergeObject {
  [k: string]: string;
}

function mergeToObject(keys: string[], values: string[]): mergeObject {
  return keys.reduce((acc: mergeObject, curr: string[], index: number) => {
    acc[curr] = values[index];
    return acc;
  }, {});
}

const result = mergeToObject(['a', 'b', 'c'], ['x', 'y', 'z']); // => { a: 'x', b: 'y', c: 'z' }
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

The generic solution to this problem would look like this:

```
function mergeToObject<
  K extends string[], 
  V extends any[],
  RT extends { 
    [I in keyof K as K[I] extends string ? K[I] : never]: V[Exclude<I, number> & keyof V] 
  }
>(keys: readonly [...K], values: readonly [...V]): RT {

  const object: Record<string, any> = {}
  for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    object[keys[i]] = values[i]
  }
  return object as RT
}
```

We store the `keys` and the `values` arrays in the generic tuple types `K` and `V`. The return type of the function will be stored in `RT`. For `RT` we map over `K` and use `K[I]` as the key name for each property. `V[I]` will be used as the type for each property. Since TypeScript does not know that `V` can be indexed with `I`, we have to use this syntax: `V[Exclude<I, number> & keyof V]`.

Some tests to see if it's working:

```
const object = mergeToObject(['a', 'b', 'c'], ['x', 23, new Date()])
//    ^? const object: { a: string; b: number; c: Date; }

object.a
object.b
object.c
object.d // Error: Property 'd' does not exist on type '{ a: string; b: number; c: Date; }'



const object2 = mergeToObject(['e', 'f', 'g'], [23, 'y', undefined])
//    ^? const object2: { e: number; f: string; g: undefined; }

object2.e
object2.f
object2.g
object2.d // Error: Property 'd' does not exist on type '{ e: number; f: string; g: undefined; }
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAWwKYCcDmqAqcDyARgFarQA8AUIogNKKoAeUqYAJgM6IdToxiYA2gF0ANImqIAag2atOiAIZgAniNGSASjlkt2XAN4SaNQQElE-RAGtUKuMDpKutc8N3yuPPgMQB%20OjdEAC5EMFQANwxhUKlBAFFGCAAbEDZUcjNxMBBkQgwAPkQAMhs7B2l3SQBfSgKAClsVDlD0VEU2BGSVREEAOgHaMUQIxVTUFsQ2jq6e-oGpYQBKUO1EA0pJCAQeRDgSMihVsjh0NnJvfkxxZRUigF512ppgU8R65NQoS0RHgAYANw-chlZp9T4CKAACyBMAA1HClutJDR9qRoIImhxBDBhO5HqNxtjcTVJG0oCB0Eg0YdnIhtJRapttmBdjToL8UBhsHgiOioPVBAByRRC8RCwhixBCiBC4bCxhSgBMAGZsqgAO6IAAiihY9SWy0oAHpjSZEAA9PybdlQPqKSi2vqER0HaB9CCu-l9NiIU2IeLodCnUIABWDAAcMFAekK2ELEJ0JmE4N8mDA2UgY1HpUZFKFLgIgYRQjk8hggRBQrqWEDqkLNsydt9bUrOWgsLgCG6BcLUFKhcAB5g5eJBKrxSopeB0sB%20Kg2Eb-SYrTae0q%20qgvYcN8Bt9AN5h91AN77-YHg%20gw5Ho7H44m4MmwKnZBmW1mVDmhUZUKXcvl0CBYAC14K4gUwUIZ1QOdwjYOsgA)